# modify parent QWidget inside child QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QWidget B which is contained inside a QWidget A. QWidget A has a QLabel. I have some data inside QWidget B, which I want to set as the value of the QLabel. How can something like this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if I understand your topic correctly, you have your own derivations of QWidget for A and B.

The clean solution to your problem is that B emits a signal, like `newLabelText(QString text);`.
Then, A provides a slot `setLabelText(QString text);`. You connect the signal to the slot and you are done.

In this solution, only one entity needs to know both A and B to perform the Signal/Slot-Connection, while A and B do not have to know each other, or mangle with each other.